# Spring MyBatis relationship mapping problem

Tags: java, spring-boot, h2, mybatis

I am using MyBatis with h2 database for learning purposes. I have a problem when I want to insert child object inside a parent object in a query, then I got an exception.

Student class

```
public class Student {
  private Long id;
  private String name;
  private Index index;

  public Student(Long id, String name, Index index) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.index = index;
  }
// getters and setters..
}
```

Index class

```
public class Index {
  private Long id;
  private String number;

  public Index() { }

  public Index(Long id, String number) {
    this.id = id;
    this.number = number;
  }
// getters and setters..
}
```

Student repository

```
@Mapper
@Repository
public interface StudentRepo {

  @Select("SELECT * FROM student WHERE id=#{id}")
  Student findById(long id);
                 // exception occurs for index field, which is my child object
  @Insert("INSERT INTO student VALUES(#{id}, #{name}, #{index})")
  int insert(Student student);
}
```

Index repository

```
@Mapper
@Repository
public interface IndexRepo {

  @Select("SELECT * FROM index WHERE id =#{id}")
  Index findById(long id);

  @Insert("INSERT INTO index VALUES(#{id}, #{number})")
  int insert(Index index);
}
```

Exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Type handler was null on parameter mapping for property 'index'. It was either not specified and/or could not be found for the javaType (com.example.batis.domain.Index) : jdbcType (null) combination.
``
```

Comment: Which property of `Index` are you trying to insert? If it's `id`, for example, you need to write `#{index.id}` instead.

Comment: Yes, I was trying to insert id. Thanks, that soloved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

The error happens because you did not instructed mybatis how to convert object of type `Index` to the value that is stored in `student` table (the id of the `Index` I assume).

You need to specify how to get the value to be stored from the object that is available like this:

```
@Insert("INSERT INTO student VALUES(#{id}, #{name}, #{index.id})")
int insert(Student student);
```

Answer (score 0):

As ave mentioned, I had to put field next to index, so working code is

```
@Mapper
@Repository
public interface StudentRepo {

  @Select("SELECT * FROM student WHERE id=#{id}")
  Student findById(long id);

  @Insert("INSERT INTO student VALUES(#{id}, #{name}, #{index.id})")
  int insert(Student student);
}
```